# Angular Material: my-select - selectionChange

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular Component I have created this formGroup:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({         
  address: new FormGroup({
    ...
    country: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(2)]),
    ....
  }),
```

and in my template I have tried this:

```
   <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Land" formControlName="country" (selectionChange)="countryChanged(country)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let countryType of countryTypes" [value]="countryType">
                {{countryType | translate}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

but it does not work like this - country is always undefined **countryChanged(country)**?

Comment: what does your `countryChanged` do?

Comment: You can use `this.form.address.valuechanges.subscribe...`, if you want to handle any change in your form use `this.form.valuechanges`.

Comment: countryChanged fetches provinceTypes of country from server

Answer (score 0):

Replacing **country** with **$event** should do the job.

```
(selectionChange)="countryChanged($event)"
```